# Не подключается БД MSQL через php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Не находит почему-то таблицу в sql. Вроде всё правильно, но пишет что не может найти таблицу.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот код connect.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "hospital_kyrsovaya";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES 'UTF8' ");
//$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
//mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES 'UTF8' ");

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT doctor FROM hospital_kyrsovaya";

if($result = $conn->query($sql)){
    $rowsCount = $result->num_rows;
    echo "Полученных объектов: $rowsCount";

    echo "<table>";
    foreach($result as $row){
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["id_doctor"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["first_name"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["last_name"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["third_name"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["specialization"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["category"] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    $result->free();
}else{
    echo "Ошибка: ".$conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

в index.php подключаю этот файл

```
<?php
    require("connect.php");
    ?>
```

на сайте пишет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На вашем же скриншоте видно, что есть только таблицы `diagnoz`, `doctor`, `pacient` и `visits`, а вы пытаетесь выполнить sql-запрос к таблице `hospital_kyrsovaya`, которая не существует, судя по скриншоту

Comment: @andreymal, он вроде как нашёл таблицу, но почему-то кодировка не читается на сайте. Вопросительные знаки пишет
Полученных объектов: 3
1 ???????? ???? ????????? ????-????????? ??????
2 ???????? ??????? ???????????? ????-???????? ??????
3 ?????? ?????? ?????????? ????-?????? ??????

Comment: Кодировка страницы, бд, скрипта должны согласоваться. Если нет - будете получать вопросительные знаки